Advantages of Scheduling through Apex than compared to the UI
I'm exploring the options for scheduling tasks within Salesforce, and I'm particularly interested in understanding the benefits of utilizing Apex for scheduling compared to using the built-in UI scheduler. Can someone outline the advantages of leveraging Apex for scheduling tasks, including any performance enhancements, flexibility in customization, and potential use cases where Apex scheduling shines over the UI scheduler? Additionally, are there any best practices or considerations to keep in mind when opting for Apex scheduling

I think this is best visualized as a table.



Feature
Apex
Apex Better
UI scheduler
UI Better




Constructor
Any constructor you want
✅
Default only
❌


Member data
Any non-static, serializable data
✅
Default only
❌


Frequency
Hourly, daily, weekly, intervals
✅
Daily, weekly, monthly only
❌


Start Date
Determined by CRON string
❌
Any date you want
✅


End Date
Never required
✅
Always required
❌


Timing
Can schedule to the second
✅
Can only be scheduled to nearest hour
❌



Realistically, the only advantage of the UI scheduler is you can schedule for a job to start and end on specific dates that Apex can't do well, or at all. For example, in Apex, it's impossible to schedule a job that starts on a specific Tuesday, runs on Tuesdays, Thursdays, and Saturdays, and ends on a specific Thursday. You'd have to instead schedule it just before the Tuesday it is first supposed to run on, and abort it after the final Thursday run. You can build this into the scheduler, but you don't get it "for free."
In practice, this advantage rarely matters. Aside from not being able to set a start or end date explicitly, Apex is better than the UI in every way. You can run jobs as frequently as every hour, can specify a wide range of hourly, daily, weekly, or monthly combinations, the scheduler never needs to end, and you can even make a scheduler that can accept parameters to customize the behavior without deploying code changes.
So, the question is not "Advantages of Scheduling through Apex than compared to the UI?" It is "Why Would You Ever Want To Use The Scheduler UI?" The answer to that is: it's convenient. Even a non-admin who has never seen a single line of code can't manage to mess this up. Just click a few buttons, and they're done. If that's your use case, it's perfectly serviceable. If you need anything even remotely more complicated, Apex is the way to go.
